# Application crash when navigating to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I am using 3 fragments with 1 activity for user profile features. I use navigation to move to fragments:
[image: Nav Graph]

The problem is when I go from profileFragment to editProfileFragment, change user's data and then go back to profileFragment by navigation action, I cannot reach editProfileFragment again from profileFragment. I got this error:

```
Navigation action/destination xxx:id/action_profileFragment_to_editProfileFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(xxx:id/editProfileFragment)
```

I am trying to use MVVM architecture so my navigation goes like this - in fragment I observe LiveData:

```
navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        viewModel.navigateTo.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver {
            navController.navigate(it)
        })
```

viewModel 'navigateTo':

```
private val _navigateTo = MutableLiveData<Event<Int>>()
    val navigateTo: LiveData<Event<Int>> = _navigateTo
```

and the navigation methods:

```
fun goBackToProfile(){
        _navigateTo.value = Event(R.id.action_editProfileFragment_to_profileFragment)
    }

fun editProfileButtonClick() {
        _navigateTo.value = Event(R.id.action_profileFragment_to_editProfileFragment)
    }
```

I also use Event wrapper class by Jose Alcerreca:

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */

    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}

class EventObserver<T>(private val onEventUnhandledContent: (T) -> Unit) : Observer<Event<T>> {
    override fun onChanged(event: Event<T>?) {
        event?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
            onEventUnhandledContent(it)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if error occurs because of Event wrapper or I do something wrong with navigation. I will appreciate any advices.

EDIT:
navigation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="xxx.mainPackage.views.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="xxx.mainPackage.views.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_editProfileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/editProfileFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/editProfileFragment"
        android:name="xxx.mainPackage.views.EditProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_edit_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_profile" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_editProfileFragment_to_chooseImageFragment"
            app:destination="@id/chooseImageFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_editProfileFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/chooseImageFragment"
        android:name="xxx.mainPackage.views.ChooseImageFragment"
        android:label="ChooseImageFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_chooseImageFragment_to_editProfileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/editProfileFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your `navigation.xml`?

Comment: Code in edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're navigating the wrong way.

**Firstly**

You are moving from `ProfileFragment` to `EditProfileFragment`. Then you move from `EditProfileFragment` to `ProfileFragment` via action whose id is `R.id.action_profileFragment_to_editProfileFragment`.

That action I see you define from Fragment `ProfileFragment`, not `EditFragment`.

Make sure your LiveData `navigateTo` in `EditProfileFragment` trigger id is `R.id.action_editProfileFragment_to_profileFragment` when you want to open `ProfileFragment` from `EditProfileFragment`.

**Secondly**

When you return from `EditProfileFragment` , don't call `navController.navigate()` as it will keep your current fragment in the backstack and push your target fragment to the backstack. If you want to go back without keeping your current fragment in the backstack, call `navController.popBackStack()`.

Comment: I see the problem, it works now, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Error is very clear, there is no `action_profileFragment_to_editProfileFragment` defined on `editProfileFragment`. if you look at your navigation xml, you can see that `action_profileFragment_to_editProfileFragment` is defined for `ProfileFragment`.

But you are trying to use this navigation action from `EditProfileFragment`, which causes the error. so either update your navigation to include this action for `EditProfileFragment` or use some action which is already defined for `EditProfileFragment`.